# pandas subset two dataframes based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

So, I have two datasets(I mean dataframe) as follows
dataframe 1:

```
name, age, id, acctno
abc, 23, 1001, 238238
dhd, 22, 2001, 299299
ddg, 30, 2920, 101010
ssd, 53, 1901, 238003
ggh, 52, 2221, 222222
eet, 50, 9920, 111111
```

(we can save this as population1.csv)

dataframe 2:

```
name, age, id, acctno
abc, 11, 1001, 238238
def, 55, 2001, 299299
xxy, 90, 2020, 101010
```

(we can save this as population2.csv)

So, we can read the data as follows

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('population1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('population2.csv')
```

And, I want to get the following result

```
res = df1-df2
```

based on the common columns of `id` and `acctno`.
We can see that based on `id` and `acctno`,
dataframe2 is in dataframe1. But the dataframe1 has some more
records that are not common in dataframe2.

Subsetting two dataframes based on one column is straightforeword,
however would like to know how to  subset two dataframes based on two 
columns.

So, the result should as something as follows

```
ssd, 53, 1901, 238003
ggh, 52, 2221, 222222
eet, 50, 9920, 111111
```

Comment: I believe you have a typo in `df2`.  I think the `id` for the fourth row should be `2920`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Setup

```
def rpd(text='', sep='\s{1,}', *args, **kwargs):
  kw = dict(engine='python', sep=sep)
  return pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(text), *args, **kw, **kwargs)

df1 = rpd(sep=',\s*', text="""\
name, age, id, acctno
abc, 23, 1001, 238238
dhd, 22, 2001, 299299
ddg, 30, 2920, 101010
ssd, 53, 1901, 238003
ggh, 52, 2221, 222222
eet, 50, 9920, 111111""")

df2 = rpd(sep=',\s*', text="""\
name, age, id, acctno
abc, 11, 1001, 238238
def, 55, 2001, 299299
xxy, 90, 2020, 101010""")
```

---

### `mask`

```
df2_tups = [*zip(df2.id, df2.acctno)]
mask = [t not in df2_tups for t in zip(df1.id, df1.acctno)]
df1[mask]

  name  age    id  acctno
2  ddg   30  2920  101010
3  ssd   53  1901  238003
4  ggh   52  2221  222222
5  eet   50  9920  111111
```

---

### `merge`

The `merge` function/method has an `indicator` argument that if set to `True` adds a column that tells you which of the data sources the merging identifiers were in.  In your case, you want to grab the ones that are left only.

```
df1.merge(
    df2[['id', 'acctno']], how='left', indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)

  name  age    id  acctno
2  ddg   30  2920  101010
3  ssd   53  1901  238003
4  ggh   52  2221  222222
5  eet   50  9920  111111
```

[Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lwR23rT-OzmSPtPAQBemBg40l5h-K_Vo)

[GitHub](https://github.com/pirsquared/Colaboratory/blob/master/pandas_subset_two_dataframes_based_on_multiple_columns.ipynb)

Comment: Woooow, I _love_ how you've embraced the CoLab runtime!

Comment: @coldspeed yeah I think I’m going to like it

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `concat`, where we `concat` `df1`, `df2`, then `df2` again so all rows from `df2` are guaranteed to be dropped (this may be memory inefficient if your DataFrames are very large):

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df2]).drop_duplicates(['id', 'acctno'], keep=False)

  name  age    id  acctno
2  ddg   30  2920  101010
3  ssd   53  1901  238003
4  ggh   52  2221  222222
5  eet   50  9920  111111
```

If you have duplicates in `df1` that you wish to keep, this answer will ignore your wishes.

Comment: Clever! But what if some duplicates in df1 were intentional 

Comment: I'll call it a "feature" of my answer :)  but that's a good point, I will clarify

Answer (score 3):

`isin` with `apply` `tuple`

```
df1.loc[~df1[['id', 'acctno']].apply(tuple,1).isin(df2[['id', 'acctno']].apply(tuple,1))]
Out[215]: 
  name  age    id  acctno
2  ddg   30  2920  101010
3  ssd   53  1901  238003
4  ggh   52  2221  222222
5  eet   50  9920  111111
```